# Error when trying to Delete Line from TextFile from ListView Item Click - Android C#

Tags: c#, android, listview, text-files, streamwriter

I am trying to delete a line from a Text File by clicking on the listed string item in a ListView, but i am getting an error.

The method I am using is to Store the TextFile lines in a `Line<string> lines` variable and Overwrite the TextFile by making the file empty, the storing the `Line<string> lines` back into the file.

Delete Line Code:

```
private void lvNotes_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    //Where I want the Line to be deleted!

    string toast = "Deleted: " + notesList.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
    Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();

    string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    string filename = Path.Combine(path, "test.txt");

    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        // 3
        // Use while != null pattern for loop
        string line;
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // 4
            // Insert logic here.
            // ...
            // "line" is a line in the file. Add it to our List.
            lines.Add(line);
        }

        using (StreamWriter swOvewrite = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(filename, "");
            swOvewrite.WriteLine(lines);
            swOvewrite.Close();

            UpdateList();

        }
    }
}
```

The Error I am getting is shown below:
[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open a file for reading and simultaneously write to it. What you need to do is to read the contents out firstly, close the reader and then create a writer and write stuff back to the file.

Another option is to write to a totally different  *temp* file and then replace the original file with the temp file.

Or open the file for both reading and writing:

```
FileStream s2 = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
```

Comment: Oh I see! I will give it a try as soon as I can.

Comment: How exactly would i Read, and Replace / Overwrite the file?